# Cannot clear QLabel content after paint event in eventFilter

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots, qlabel

I use QLabel and eventFilter() to display captured image from camera stream whenever user clicks on Capture button. This event works well, the image is shown on the QLabel.
I have another Mode button, when the user clicks on Mode button, the mode setting is changed and the QLabel should get cleared. However, the `ChangeModeSlot()` got invoked but the `ui->lbl_capture->clear()` does not work, the old captured image is still displayed on the QLabel.
Am I using the right function, anyone know how to clear content of QLabel properly?

```
Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form){
 ui->setupUi(this);
 ui->lbl_capture->installEventFilter(this);
 connect(image_capture, SIGNAL(CaptureImageSignal(cv::Mat)), this, SLOT(CaptureImageSlot(cv::Mat)));
 connect(ui->btn_mode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ChangeModeSlot()));
 }

 void Form::CaptureImageSlot(cv::Mat img){
    img.copyTo(captured_img);
    ui->lbl_capture->update();
 }

 void Form::ChangeModeSlot(){
     /*Do some other stuffs before clear the label content*/
     ui->lbl_capture->clear();//clear the current image
 }

 bool Form::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
     if(watched == ui->lbl_capture && event->type() == QEvent::Paint){
         QPainter painter(ui->lbl_capture);                             painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
         QImage img((const unsigned char *)(captured_img.data), captured_img.cols, captured_img.rows, captured_img.step1(), QImage::Format_RGB888);

         QRectF target;
         target.setLeft(0);
         target.setTop(0);
         target.setSize(ui->lbl_capture->size());

         QRectF source;
         source.setLeft(0);
         source.setTop(0);
         source.setSize(img.size());

         painter.drawImage(target,img, source);
         return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: But after clearing label you will have another Paint event where your image will be drawn again. Have you tried to clear `captured_img` in `Form::ChangeModeSlot` instead of clearing `QLabel`?

Comment: I think it is painted again too but how could that happen because the update() occurs only when I click on Capture button. I have not tried clearing captured_img, maybe it could help.